# How can I pass an encoded url as a path parameter in c#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I am creating a new RESTful API which has an endpoint

`GET v1/my-resource/{encoded-url}`

When I try and send a message to this endpoint, I get a 404

`GET v1/my-resource/%2Fshop%2Fgender-women-category-bags`

When I try and send `my-url` it returns a 200.

`GET v1/my-resource/my-url`

This is my method:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("")]
public class GetController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("v1/my-resource/{url}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetResource(
        [FromRoute, Required] string url)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why I can't pass `%2Fshop%2Fgender-women-category-bags` as the encoded url?

Comment: I wonder if the URL is being decoded by the framework. You could try `[HttpGet("v1/my-resource/{**url}")]`?

Comment: no luck :*( What does the `**` do?

Comment: It's a catch-all route, basically everything after `/my-resource/` would be included in the `url` variable. Note, I cannot replicate your problem in my code here.

Comment: checking this again, it does look like it worked, it just decoded the string, so I got `/shop/gender-women-category-bags`.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could try to base64 encode it so it produces a solid sequence and it doesn't confuse the ApiController.
Btw. I've tried your solution in a mvc controller and it works, but not in api controller.

Comment: its a good idea, but I don't have control over the route.  This is already an agreed contract